# How to decrease the price error of yield curve estimated using differential evolution?

Tags: r, optimization, differential-evolution

I am optimizing the parameters of Nelson Siegel Sevenson(NSS) model for estimating the yield curve. For that am using DEoptim package of R but results are not coming that satisfactory. Can you suggest me some other methods

I tried PSO, LM algorithms but they were giving some errors.

I am attaching the code that I have used for DEoptim

```
 sol <- DEoptim(fn = OF2,lower = Data$min,upper = Data$max, control = list(CR 
  = 0.9,NP = 110,F= 0.7,itermax = 2000,trace = FALSE))
```

So can you provide me the code of DEoptim(differential evolution) in R so that I can make some custom changes to improve the results.

P.S.-- I have seen R directory code of DEoptim but too complicated to understand

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give a [mcve] in your question! What does *not coming that satisfactory* mean? Eventually this is a question for StackExchange.

Comment: Price error is coming too high by this algorithm. I want to minimize that

Comment: Put additional information in your question (not in comments), i.e. **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56289047/edit